# Arduino + ESP8266 WebClient

Tags: node.js, arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide

I need to connect my ESP8266 with Arduino Mega, but I don't have any library to connect it as a ESP8266 WebClient, in Serial1.

I try to use [WifiLibrary from Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebClient).

I try to use ESP8266WiFi.h for Serial1, but I couldn't find a way to change the Serial Port.
So I can't switch WiFiClient-client for Serial1.

I need some help here, Guys.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to have both arduino and esp8266 in your system, you need to make them connected over Serial. So you can set some AT commands from arduino to send or listen data via esp8266.

Here is a cool answer for you :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084668/3082873